# Help me choose a suitable Scheme implementation

Tags: scheme

This seems to be really too much to ask for, given the systematically outdated content on this topic that is scattered throughout the internet.

I simply can't find a noiseless and up to date list of available Scheme implementations (except [there](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-standards#implementations), but I'd have enjoyed a colorful feature summarizing table) so I'm asking the community instead of trying dozens of implementations of a language I don't master yet. Help me enjoy this amazing language.

Requirements:

- Free (as in speech)
- Lightweight: no unnecessary libraries beyond the standard, must compile fast. Anything lighter than Guile qualifies as lightweight.
- R6RS (no troll please, I'm learning the language and feel the need to stick to something standard)
- No .NET, no JVM
- Should work at least on Linux
- Should work at least on x86
- Easy FFI
- Bonus point for fast implementations (too bad Bigloo doesn't support R6RS).

I'm currently using Ypsilon, that I find great, but not maintained since 2008. Guile can be a good competitor, but it seems quite heavy (and FFI is far easier with Ypsilon).

I may be missing some quality implementations, so feel free to share your experiences.

**UPDATE** Thank you for your answers, I will go for Larceny, since it provides pretty much everything I am looking for. Happy scheming to all of you !

Comment: @Skeptic: good point. Let me enhance.

Comment: Not trolling, but I doubt you'll find an R6RS implementation that meets *all* of these. You'll either end up compromising on "lightweight", "free" or one of the "lesser" (my word) requirements on this list.

Comment: I know you're not excited about Guile, but 2.x is much nicer than the 1.x you get with most distros.  It's a little tough to compile on Debian-based systems, but it's much easier if you compile the garbage collection libraries yourself.

Comment: I'd be interested in your experience trying out Larceny. How far did you get? Did you switch away? Du you still use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/).  Its documentation and IDE are pretty good, it's JIT-compiled, and it supports a variety of languages including R<sup>6</sup>RS.  The only requirement of yours that I'm not sure Racket fulfills is being lightweight—it's a matter of perspective whether that's true for it or not.

If you don't care about the heaps of functionality that Racket provides, [Larceny](http://www.larcenists.org/) might warrant consideration as well.  It was written by Will Clinger, who was personally involved in the R<sup>6</sup>RS process.  Larceny is one of the most complete implementations of R<sup>6</sup>RS.  Petite Larceny can be tricky to compile, but this may not matter much depending on the platform you're targeting.

Finally, there's [Chez Scheme](http://www.scheme.com/).  I have no experience with it; it has a reputation of being an efficient and well-supported Scheme, though.  In any case, note that, as far as I can tell, you need the commercial license if you want access to the FFI.

**Edit:** Added Larceny and Chez Scheme.

Comment: Thanks. Chez Scheme isn't free (added to requirements). Larceny looks good, indeed. Their benchmarks pointed me to Ikarus, which looks perfect, but unmaintained. Racket however seems to depart from the simplicity aesthetics which characterize Scheme.

Comment: @Alexandre: Not to "troll", but, R6RS and simplicity go together like water and oil. Any implementation that tries to do both will have to compromise, to some degree, on either/both. The question, then, is how much compromise you are willing to accept in each criterion.

Comment: @Chris: "no troll" means that I have my reasons for using R6RS, the main one being that I am learning the language and I'd like to stick to something standard. I'll consider simple an implementation which only provides R6RS.

Comment: As a Racket developer, I'm incredibly biased, but let me draw your attention to Python, Ruby, and Haskell; each one is a "principal implementation" language. Along the same lines, Racket is a "principal implementation" language... which happens to include all of Scheme.

Comment: It is also worth noting that much of Larceny infrastructure (e.g. its Twobit compiler) was developed well before R6RS, and thus its source code probably makes more sense when read in the context of the earlier RnRS reports.  (I point this out mostly as a reaction to reading Alexandre's desire to "stick to something standard.")

Answer (score 5):

while it may not fulfill all of your requirements, i've been having a lot of fun with [chicken](http://www.call-cc.org/), which has a vibrant community and lots of libraries for practical applications.

Comment: +1 - Literally the only requirement here that doesn't fit is that Chicken is R5RS standard vs R6RS - and it would be better in my mind if the author learned the "heart" of scheme - it doesn't take much effort at all to learn the differences between the standards.

Answer (score 3):

[Racket](http://www.racket-lang.org/) (formerly PLT Scheme) is one of the best implementations, is actively maintained, and includes R<sup>6</sup>RS support.

Comment: Thanks. However, Racket seems too heavy though.

Answer (score 1):

[Chez Scheme](https://www.scheme.com/) has been [open sourced](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme) and therefore now meets your insistence on "free" (as in speech) software. It is also an extremely robust implementation and compiler, with a robust heritage. It is also fully R6RS compliant, and the author Kent Dybvig was one of steering committee for the standard.

I recommend using it's REPL from within [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) using [Geiser](https://www.nongnu.org/geiser/).

Comment: Nice to know. I moved away from Scheme a few years ago, but I'm still interested in the way the interpreters are implemented.